# Tkinter Screen Size and Propagation

Tags: python, tkinter, screen, screen-resolution

The code below is supposed to be one large `Text` widget containing a variable number of smaller `Text` widgets gridded on to an embedded `Frame`. As `Text` widget height is measured in lines I hoped to make the internal `Text` widgets stick to the vertical borders of the `Frame` (which is measured in pixels) using `sticky` so that it would adjust to different monitor sizes.

I have two problems with the code below. One is the screen resolution.

```
self.winfo_screenheight()
```

gives me a height that is 72 pixels too high--the bottom of the window goes off the screen. I had to manually adjust it to make it fit. Is this to do with the Tkinter window title? I assume that 72 pixels would not be consistent across monitors. How can I dynamically adjust for this?

Secondly, I have set the embedded `Frame` to `propagate(0)` but when the internal `Text` widgets are added it shrinks back to their default size. If you uncomment out the `return` command halfway down, you can see that it does fill the screen vertically before the Text widgets are added. I assume that by embedding the `Frame` using

```
self.text_box.window_create(tk.END, window = self.win_frame)
```

it is the `window` that is propagating and not the `Frame`.

Is there any way around these problems. Any insight would be helpful.

Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as St

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.num_win = 7
        self.win_width = 40

        #Set up the root window Note the -72 hack to get it to fit
        self.screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight() - 72
        self.screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.geometry("{}x{}+-10+-0".format(self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Set up the mother Text widget that will hold the smaller ones
        self.vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.vbar.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="EW")
        self.text_box = tk.Text(self, xscrollcommand=self.vbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)
        self.text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 5), sticky="NESW")
        self.vbar.config(command=self.text_box.xview)
        self.text_box.propagate(0)

        #Set up the Frame to grid the internal widgets to.
        self.win_frame = ttk.Frame(self.text_box, width = self.win_width * self.num_win, height =
                                   self.screen_height)
        self.win_frame.propagate(0)
        self.text_box.window_create(tk.END, window = self.win_frame)

        #return

        #Set up the internal text widgets
        self.internal_windows = []
        for n in range (0, self.num_win):
            self.internal_windows.append(St.ScrolledText(self.win_frame, width=self.win_width))
            self.internal_windows[n].grid(column=n*2, row=0, sticky="NSEW", pady=5, padx=5)
            for x in range(1, 100):
                self.internal_windows[n].insert(tk.END, "{}\n".format(x))

main = Main()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Noticed that you used `.propagate(0)`. Should you not use `.grid_propagate(0)`? Why do `column=n*2` and not just `n`? Have you got a sketch of the GUI you want to create so I can better understand your end goal?

Comment: Is `self.win_width` in pixel units or character? You have applied it to `ttk.Frame` which treats this input as pixel, and when you applied it to 'ScrolledText' it will treat it as you are asking for so many character wide. So your ScrollText width will be significantly larger than your ttk.Frame width.

Comment: I tried .grid_propagate(0) but the other windows don't open at all unless there is a mistake somewhere else. column=n*2 is a left over from when I was using a standard Text widget and gridding a scrollbar adjacent to it in the adjacent column. It is unnecessary now.

Comment: self.win_width is in characters. The width is fine. They are all nested inside a Text widget so I can use the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom to view them all. The problem is with getting the internal text widgets to the screen vertical size.

Comment: Yes, there are a few errors/mistakes piling up. Start with ensuring your syntax is correct and that should be the basis to work from. Enable the various widgets to have different background colours so you can visualise the GUI you are creating. One widget at a time. I can see from my end that 2 x self.win_width, your frame has to be 600 pixel wide.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve by putting a text widget inside a text widget?

Answer (score 0):

Bryan Oakley has asked you a very practical question. Not withstanding that, I have revised your script (see below) based on my limited understanding that you are trying to use a text widget to scroll a frame consisting of 7 Scrolltext widgets placed side by side each other and touching the window title bar. You also seem to want the frame to cover `self.text_box` and the text_box to be of a defined size.

**Main amendments made to your script:**

1. Changed `.propagate(0)` to `.grid_propagate(0)`.
2. Changed frame to have a larger width than just `self.win_width * self.num_win` as `self.win_width referred to 42 characters wide and was not correctly used to define the frame width.
3. Showed you how to configure a ttk widget's background colour to
   visualise it's implementation and trouble-shoot your tkinter script.

The fact that you see the widgets in `self.internal_windows` surrounded in pink color evidences that those widgets are grid inside `self.win_frame`.

I had reverted your script to use `self.winfo_screenheight()` instead of `self.winfo_screenheight() -72`.

**Side note:** For scrolling purposes, I learnt that folks usually used a 'tk.Canvas' and a `Scrollbar` to create a `Scrollable Frame`. I recently wrote a script for a [Vertical Scroll Frame](https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets) and you may look at amending it to do horizontal scrolling.

**Revised Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as St

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.num_win = 7
        self.win_width = 40

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('frame.TFrame', background='pink', borderwidth=5,
                             relief='raised')

        #Set up the root window Note the -72 hack to get it to fit
        self.screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        #self.screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight() - 72
        self.screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.geometry("{}x{}+-10+-0".format(self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        print('self.screen_height = ', self.screen_height)
        print('self.screen_width = ', self.screen_width)

        #Set up the mother Text widget that will hold the smaller ones
        self.hbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.hbar.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="EW")
        self.text_box = tk.Text(self, xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, wrap=tk.NONE)
        self.text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(5, 5), sticky="NESW")
        self.hbar.config(command=self.text_box.xview)
        self.text_box.grid_propagate(0)

        #Set up the Frame to grid the internal widgets to.
        width = self.win_width * self.num_win
        print('width = ', width)
        self.win_frame = ttk.Frame(self.text_box, style='frame.TFrame',
                                   width = 310*self.num_win,
                                   #height = self.screen_height,
                                   )
        self.text_box.window_create(tk.END, window = self.win_frame)

        #Set up the internal text widgets
        self.internal_windows = []
        for n in range (0, self.num_win):
            self.internal_windows.append(St.ScrolledText(self.win_frame,
                                                         width=self.win_width))
            self.internal_windows[n].grid(column=n, row=0, sticky="NSEW",
                                          pady=5, padx=5)
            for x in range(1, 100):
                self.internal_windows[n].insert(tk.END, "{}\n".format(x))
        self.win_frame.configure(height=self.screen_height)
        self.win_frame.grid_propagate(0)

main = Main()

main.mainloop()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Why aren't self.internal_windows the same height as self,win_frame when you have set sticky to "NSEW"?

Comment: I used `self.win_frame.configure(height=self.screen_height)` to enlarge `self.win_frame`'s height to that of the screen. I thought this was what you wanted. If you comment this command, the height of `self,win_frame` will default to the height of `self.internal_windows` due to the `sticky=NSEW` option.  This will mean `self.text_box` will become exposed. Is this what you want? Hope this explanation helps. BTW, are you still needing to hard code the 72 pixel height on your system? I did not need to do that on my system, Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks again for trying. I should have explained myself more clearly. The pink window (self.win_frame) is the size I want it ie. full screen size. But I want the internal text widgets to also be the same height so vertically they completely cover the pink frame from the top of that window to the bottom.

Comment: `self.internal_windows.append(St.ScrolledText(self.win_frame, width=self.win_width, height=69))` Add the height option. :)

Comment: Apart from hard coding, you could use `.metrics(linespace)` on the Font object to get the height in pixel of each row of text then do the necessary arithmetic against the screen height to approximate the number of rows you may need for `self.internal_windows`. See this [link](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html) for explanation of Font object. I suspect you will then also have to factor in borderwidth, horizontal scrollbar width, the window title bar....